# Frustrating Errors in Loading Motion Planning Library

Tags: ros, motion-planning, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am facing very unusual problems. I have been using ROS-Indigo under Ubuntu 14.04 on my Virtual Machine and ROS-Indgio under Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. Surprisingly, I am seeing totally different kinds of errors on all of these machines while I am using the same tutorials.

Coming to the point, I am trying to run PR2 moveit tutorials given [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/ros_visualization/visualization_tutorial.html). On my laptop, I am seeing the following error

```
PluginlibFactory: The plugin for class 'moveit_rviz_plugin/MotionPlanning' failed to load.  Error: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class moveit_rviz_plugin/MotionPlanning with base class type rviz::Display does not exist.
```

and the following error

```
Exception while loading planner 'ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner': According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner with base class type planning_interface::PlannerManager does not exist.
```

It is really very frustrating. So, I tried to run it on my virtual machine as well. Please help me, how can I handle this. I have been spending a lot of time on it and it is not working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245752/frustrating-errors-in-loading-motion-planning-library/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both of these errors point to missing packages. Do you have the `ros-<distro>-moveit-ros-visualization` and the `ros-<distro>-moveit-planners-ompl` packages installed?

Similar Q/A: [moveit rviz plugin error](http://answers.ros.org/question/192369).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-10-16**:
Thank you so gvdhoorn. It is working now. I am so grateful to you for your comment. I spent almost 2 days in figuring out what's the problem and tried to install as many packages to resolve this but I could not. May Mighty Lord accept your good deeds and help you when you need.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-16**:
No problem. But I'm curious how you installed the PR2 pkgs in the first place. They should've resulted in the missing pkgs being installed automatically.

And in general: if something complains about plugins not being found, try to find out which pkg they should come with. Then install that.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-10-16**:
I shall definitely do it and be careful in future. Thank gvdhoorn for your extremely valuable time.